# Where does the roughness map go?

Tags: textures, unity

So I used Quixel, and created a great item. I want to view it in Unity with all the maps the problem however is I have 5 maps but only know how to insert 4.

Diffuse
Normal
AO
Specular
Roughness

I don't see a slot for roughness (AKA gloss).
[image]

Comment: I downloaded my texture from [https://www.texturecan.com/details/31/](https://www.texturecan.com/details/31/) and I found that there's no specular/metalness texture but there is a roughness (aka gloss) texture, soo, what I'm supposed to do with this last texture?

Answer (score 2):

Okay it took some researching but apparently my software I was using don't do all the heavy lifting. You copy & paste the roughness into the alpha channel of the specular/metalness texture which will do the trick (the RGB channels must be off though).

I discovered the reason for this is.

- White = Solid
- Black = Transparent

This technique must be used in lets say games where you shoot at the wall, and you see all the little bullet hole textures.

Doing more research I discovered this great guide. Which helped me further understand the decision to use an alpha.

https://www.gametextures.com/putting-your-texture-in-an-alpha-channel-using-photoshop/